# General result from Integrate differs from result with special values

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Can someone explain why these outputs differ?

```
In[5]:= g1 = 
   Integrate[Exp[-I x (n + 1)]/( Exp[I x] + 2), {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]];

In[6]:= g1 /. n -> 3
```

> During evaluation of In[6]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate
>   expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

```
Out[6]= Indeterminate

In[7]:= g2 = Integrate[Exp[-I x (3 + 1)]/( Exp[I x] + 2), {x, 0, 2 Pi}]

Out[7]= π/16
```

The last is correct, the first seems to apply some incorrect assumptions? Note

```
In[8]:= g1

Out[8]= 2^(-1 - n) Beta[-(1/2), -1 - n, 0] Sin[n π]
```

See [Background](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846459/explicit-calculation-of-laurent-series-coefficients-by-evaluating-integral?noredirect=1#comment5871931_2846459) for context.

Comment: General result is valid: `{Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 300, eps = 10^-300}, 
   N[Limit[2^(-1 - n) Beta[-(1/2), -1 - n, 0] Sin[n \[Pi]], 
     n -> 3 + eps], 100]] // Chop, N[Pi/16, 100]}`

Comment: Thanks you @MariuszIwaniuk, that answers it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround

```
g1[n_?IntegerQ] := Integrate[Exp[-I x (n + 1)]/(Exp[I x] + 2), {x, 0, 2 Pi} ];    
{g1[1], g1[2], g1[3] }
{π/4, -(π/8), π/16}
```